# Vlookup partial string match (with wild card) doesn't work

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a Vlookup partial match. My Column looks like this

```
Code               Price
24510250600          100
24510260101          20
24510260102          98
24510260201          22
24510260202          10
```

I'm given the a partial string of the Code and want to find the Price.

```
Code               Price
102506
```

My current Vlookup is

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&E11&"*",E2:H7,2,FALSE)
```

This should search 102506 and match with 24510250600  then return the price from the table but I am getting #N/A. Please advise as I don't know why the wild card function doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Are your codes numbers or text? Wildcards don't work with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that `"*"&E11&"*"` is a text string and one cannot use VLOOKUP to lookup text in numbers.

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER

```
=@FILTER(B2:B6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2,A2:A6)))
```

[image]

---

If not then use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$6)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Filter again: you're going to get a lot of upvotes for me with FILTER answers cause I can't test them at work.